# How to run an exe on a remote machine using psexec which also needs dependent dlls?

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-server, psexec

I want to run an exe on a remote machine using psexec like this:

`psexec \\remotemachine -c Example.exe param value`

Thing is this `Example.exe` has two dlls dependencies (lets say a.dll, b.dll) so when I run the above command it fails as it couldn't find the dlls on the remote machine. As i understood, `-c` option in psexec Copy the program to the remote system for execution but I suppose it will only copy the `Example.exe`. how can i pass the dlls also along with this command to run the exe successfully ?

Can any one suggest how can I run the above command successfully on remote machine?